# Galactic rotation speed

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

Rotation speed `vc[R]` in reduced units for M33 looks like

```
0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955]
```

Knowing `e=0.995`, I am trying to get the density  Rho[m]from the equation

```
vc[R]^2 == Integrate[(4 Pi Sqrt[1 - e^2] m^2  Rho[m])/  Sqrt[-e^2 m^2 + R^2], {m, 0, R}]
```

This equation comes from Galactic Dynamics Binney Tremaine 2008. (2.132)

Using trial and error, I obtain a "good" solution for `Rho[m]`, but it is very time expensive.

Does anybody knows how to solve this equation to get `Rho[m]`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the Mathematica code that you obtain a "good" solution for `Rho[m]` ?

Comment: What's the value of parameter R?

Comment: This is just an idea, but it might lead to a workable approach. Define the shorthand notation `eqn[R_, e_] = vc[R]^2 == Integrate[...]`. Then (if `e = 0.1`, for instance) evaluate `Series[eqn[R, 0.1], {R, 0, n}] // Normal // PowerExpand` for various `n = 2, 3, 4, ...`. Comparing coefficients of powers of `R` allows you to solve for the derivatives of `Rho[m]` at `m == 0`.

Comment: 1. Please show us the data text for creating the interpolating function, not a picture of it. 2. I believe all the methods below will work on this interpolating function.

Comment: I don’t understand why author  adds a new question when the old one has already received the answer?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'd say this is OK if the question is really closely related. But I'm just confused because, I believe using a `InterpolatingFunction` as `vc` should not make any (significant) difference, the methods below should all work in principle. For which part is OP having difficulty? As currently written, the new question is not clear, and as mentioned in my last comment, the data for `InterpolatingFunction` is missing for now.

Comment: @xzczd I think he should delete the extra part and start a new post explaining what didn't work for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here my third answer which solves case `R==25` .

This approach uses an interpolation-function (instead of wavelets or FEM) to describe the unknown function `rho[R]` and evaluates the integrations using Gauss quadratur.

```
e = 0.995;
v[R_] := 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955] ;
Rmin = 0; Rmax = 25;
ni = 25 ; 

Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];  

(* grid R *)
riGrid[n_] := 
Block[{dt, \[CapitalDelta]t0, \[CapitalDelta]t1, zw, sol}, 
dt = Map[ \[CapitalDelta]t0 + (\[CapitalDelta]t1 - \
\[CapitalDelta]t0) (#/Rmax)^2 &, Subdivide[0, Rmax, n]];
zw = Accumulate[dt] ;
sol = Solve[{zw[[1]] == 0,zw[[-1]] == Rmax}, {\[CapitalDelta]t0,\[CapitalDelta]t1}][[1]];
zw /. sol  // N]

ri=riGrid[ni]; (* problem adapted grid *)
\[Rho]i = Array[\[Rho], Length[ri]];
swGauss = 
 GaussianQuadratureWeights[ 15, 0, e] ;(*Stützstellen&Gewichte*)

 
zwv = Function[{RR}, Evaluate[  v[RR] ^2/(4 Pi RR^2 ) ]];

JJ = Sum[ (zwv[R]   - 
      Sqrt[1 - e^2]/
       e^3 Total@
        Map[#[[2]] #[[1]]^2 /
           Sqrt[1 - #[[1]]^2] Interpolation[
             Transpose[{Rationalize[ri], \[Rho]i}]][#[[1]]  R/e ] & , 
         swGauss] )^2, {R, ri}];
mini00 = NMinimize[{JJ }, \[Rho]i]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListPlot[Rest@Transpose[{ri, \[Rho]i} /. mini00[[2]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I see that Rémy Galli upvoted your answer, but there is no answer to the first question in your post. Maybe you need to add answer to the first question as well?

Comment: @AlexTrounev What is the " first question" ? I only tried to find the unknown density `Rho[m] `

Comment: Thank you very much (+1). :)

Answer (score 7):

We can solve this problem using colocation method with Euler wavelets ang Gauss quadrature rule. First we define interval $0\le R\le Rmax$ and map interval $(0,R)$, on `R/2 (1+z)` with $-1\le z \le 1$ in integrand, then the Volterra integral equation becomes Fredholm integral equation. Before code please call

```
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
```

Code

```
e = 0.995;
v[R_] := 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955];
Rmin = 0; Rmax = 5;
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2)  UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= 
      t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 4; M0 = 7; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; M = nn; np = nn; g = 
 GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1];
ugrid = g[[All, 1]]; weights = g[[All, 2]]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
A = Array[a, nn]; Rho[y_] := A . Psi[y];
eqs = Table[
   v[Rmax x]^2 == 
    0.31376632053307746 (Rmax x)^2/
      2 Sum[( (1 + z)^2 Rho[ 1/2 x (1 + z)] weights[[i]])/Sqrt[
       1 - 0.24750625 (1 + z)^2] /. z -> ugrid[[i]], {i, np}], {x, 
    xcol}];

{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqs, A]

sol = LinearSolve[mat // N, -vec];

rul = Table[A[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, nn}]; p=Plot[
 Rho[x/Rmax] /. rul, {x, 0, Rmax}, PlotRange -> {0, .2}, AxesLabel -> {"R", "\[Rho]"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. We can compare this solution (solid line) with Ulrich solution at `Rmax=5` (red dashed line) as follows

```
    e = 0.995;
v[R_] := 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955];
Rmin = 0; Rmax = 5;
ni = 50;
ri = Subdivide[Rmin, Rmax, ni];

f[G_] := 
  Block[{R, m, zw = Simplify[v[R] v'[R]/(2 \[Pi] R)]}, 
   Interpolation[
    Table[{R, ( 
       Sqrt[1 - e^2]/e^3 NIntegrate[( s^2 G[s R/e])/(-s^2 + 1)^(
          3/2), {s, 0, e}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] + zw )}, {R, 
      ri}]]];

solf = NestList[f, .18/(1 + #^2) &, 20]; p1 = 
 Plot[solf[[-1]][R], {R, Rmin, Rmax}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
   
    Show[p,p1]
```

[image: Figure 2]

We see a small discrepancy that disappears as the number of iterations increases.

Update 2. We can use also power series as Stephen proposed. Using `NMinimize` we can simplifier this method as follows
(*m->R/e s*)

```
int = 
 Table[Integrate[( s^2 s^i)/Sqrt[- s^2 + 1], s], {i, 0, 10}];

int0 = N[int /. s -> 10^-16, 30];

int1 = int /. s -> e;

A = Table[(R/e)^i, {i, 0, 10}]; B = Array[b, Length[A]];

dint = int1 - int0; r = Range[0, 1, 1/10];  
eq = Table[-v[R]^2 + 
    4 Pi Sqrt[1 - e^2] R^2/e^3 Sum[
      A[[i]] B[[i]] dint[[i]], {i, Length[A]}], {R, r}];

sol1 = NMinimize[eq . eq, B];

p2 = Plot[A . B /. sol1[[2]], {R, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
```

Visualization together with wavelets solution

```
Show[p,p2]
```

[image: Figure 3]

We see nice agreement for power series solution and wavelets solution. Note that we can extend power series up to `R=5` using this code

```
e = 0.995;
v[R_] := 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955];
Rmin = 0; Rmax = 5;

int = Table[Integrate[(s^2 s^i)/Sqrt[-s^2 + 1], s], {i, 0, 10}];

int0 = N[int /. s -> 10^-16, 30];

int1 = int /. s -> e;

A = Table[(R/e)^i, {i, 0, 10}]; B = Array[b, Length[A]];

dint = int1 - int0;
Do[rr[i] = Subdivide[i, i + 1, Length[A]];
  eqs[i] = 
   Table[-v[R]^2 + 
     4 Pi Sqrt[1 - e^2] R^2/e^3 Sum[
       A[[i]] B[[i]] dint[[i]], {i, Length[A]}], {R, rr[i]}];
  sol[i] = NMinimize[eqs[i] . eqs[i], B]; 
  pp[i] = Plot[A . B /. sol[i][[2]], {R, i, i + 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, PlotRange -> All];, {i, 0, 4}];
```

Finally we compare power series solution and wavelets solutions in one plot

```
Show[p,Table[pp[i], {i, 0, 4}]]
```

[image: Figure 4]

**Update 3**. To compute solution up to `R=10` we need to improve wavelets numerical algorithm using `NIntegrate` instead of the Gauss quadrature rule. So we have

```
e = 0.995; lambda = 4 Sqrt[1 - e^2] \[Pi] /e^3;
v[R_] := 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955];
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <=
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 4; M0 = 7; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
A = Array[a, nn]; Rho[y_] := A . Psi[y];
int[x_] := 
  NIntegrate[ z^2 Psi[( x z)/e]/Sqrt[1 - z^2], {z, 0, e}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 5];
eq[Rmin_, Rmax_] := 
  Table[(v[Rmin + (Rmax - Rmin) x]/(Rmin + (Rmax - Rmin) x))^2 == 
    lambda A . int[x], {x, xcol}];
```

Numerical solution

```
sol10 = NSolve[eq[0, 10], A];
```

Visualization together with `p` and separately

```
{p10 = Plot[Rho[x/10] /. sol10[[1]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, .2}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"R", "\[Rho]"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], Show[p,p10]}
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Nice answer. How did you find the restriction `0<R<1`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have published several papers on the rotation of galaxies. Actually it could be better to solve on $0\le R\le 10$. But the Euler wavelets collocation method is stably on unit interval.

Comment: I found an iterative solution which seem to work for case `Rmax=10` too

Comment: @UlrichNeumann See updated Update 1 to my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, looks really good. I am still unclear why the integration `NIntegrate[...,{m,0,R}]`  near `R==0` can be so faulty.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Because in your case the integral equation is singular at `R->0`. To remove this singularity  we can make substitution `m->s R/e`, then we come to equation as in my answer.

Comment: @ Alex Trounev  Nice solution but I don't succeed to find a solution with Rmax=10, even after reading and studying your paper Mohammad, M., Trounev, A., & Alshbool, M. (2021). A novel numerical method for solving fractional diffusion-wave and nonlinear Fredholm and Volterra integral equations with zero absolute error. Axioms, 10(3), 165.    Could you precise this point ? Thank you again for your answers Rémy

Comment: To find solution with `Rmax=10` we need numerical algorithm with absolute error of about  10^-6.  The current algorithm has error of about 10^-3. I will try to improve this algorithm. Are parameters of this model empirical?

Comment: @RémyGalli See Update 3 to my answer.

Comment: @Alex  Wonderful. In fact, R=10 represents the visible edge of galaxy M33. Visible edges of other galaxies could extend to 25 (kpc) . For this reason, it would be interesting to get a code allowing higher values for R for other galaxies.

Comment: @RémyGalli Ok! I think it would be a good question for a new discussion about extension code up to  `R=25`.

Comment: @RémyGalli In my third answer you 'll find a solution for `R=25`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Interesting update 3! Perhaps my third answer finds your interest. In this approach I try parametrized interpolation together with Gaussquadratur.

Comment: @Alex and Ulrich    Superb job . Now, suppose that v[r] is an interpolating function. How do you manage you codes to get a solution without a lot of warning ?? Thanks again, its really interesting.

Comment: @RémyGalli Please note that you can't just update your question adding a new one.  It would be better to start a new topic.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a series expansion solution based on the idea that I mentioned in an earlier comment. Within the range of validity of the series expansion it leads to a result that is numerically very similar to the result obtained by Alex Trounev.

Definitions given in the original question.

```
vc[R_] = 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955]

eqn[R_, e_] = 
 vc[R]^2 == 
  Integrate[(4 Pi Sqrt[1 - e^2] m^2 Rho[m])/Sqrt[-e^2 m^2 + R^2], {m, 0, R}]
```

The solution strategy is to use the series expansion of the equation about `R = 0` to compute the derivatives of `Rho[m]` at `m = 0`.

Check the first few terms of this series for `e = 0.995`.

```
eqnSeries = Series[eqn[R, 0.995], {R, 0, 2}] // PowerExpand;
SolveAlways[eqnSeries, R]
(* {{Rho[0] -> 0.177325}} *)
```

```
eqnSeries = Series[eqn[R, 0.995], {R, 0, 3}] // PowerExpand;
SolveAlways[eqnSeries, R]
(* {{Rho[0] -> 0.177325, Derivative[1][Rho][0] -> 0.}} *)
```

```
eqnSeries = Series[eqn[R, 0.995], {R, 0, 4}] // PowerExpand;
SolveAlways[eqnSeries, R]
(* {{Rho[0] -> 0.177325, Derivative[1][Rho][0] -> 0., (Rho^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] -> -0.593919}} *)
```

Switch to a fully algebraic solution. Save the variable values in a list of rules for later use.

```
vals = {a -> 0.342331, b -> 0.728117, c -> 0.87955, e -> 0.995};
```

Fully algebraic version of the definitions given in the question. Transform the integral using `m = R s` so that `0 < m < R` is transformed to `0 < s < 1`.

```
vc[R_, {a_, b_, c_}] = a Sqrt[R^2/(b + R^2)^c]

eqn[R_, {a_, b_, c_}, e_] = 
 vc[R, {a, b, c}]^2 == 
  R^2 Integrate[(4 Pi Sqrt[1 - e^2] s^2 Rho[R s])/Sqrt[-e^2 s^2 + 1], {s, 0, 1}]
```

Coefficient of `R^p` on the left hand side of the equation.

```
lhs[p_] = SeriesCoefficient[eqn[R, {a, b, c}, e][[1]], {R, 0, p}]

(* piecewise expression with all odd-p coefficients being zero *)
```

Series expand `Rho[x]` about `x = 0`.

```
Sum[(x^p/p!)*Derivative[p][Rho][0], {p, 0, Infinity}]
```

The `p`-th term of the series on the right hand side of the equation.

```
rhs[p_] = 
 Assuming[{0 < e <= 1, p >= 0, p \[Element] Integers}, 
  (eqn[R, {a, b, c}, e][[2]] /. {Rho[R s] -> (R s)^p/p! Derivative[p][Rho][0]})]

(* expression with a hypergeometric function in it *)
```

Equate corresponding powers on the left and right hand sides of the equation, and solve for the corresponding derivative of `Rho[x]` at `x = 0`.

```
eqnSeries = Simplify[lhs[p + 2] R^(p + 2)] == rhs[p];
soln = Solve[eqnSeries, Derivative[p][Rho][0]][[1]] // 
  Simplify[#, Assumptions -> {a > 0, 0 < b < 1, 0 < c < 1, p \[Element] Integers, p >= 0}] &

(* piecewise expression for Derivative[p][Rho][0] with all odd-p derivatives being zero *)
```

Substitute in the numerical values of the variables.

```
solnN = soln /. vals // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> {p \[Element] Integers, p >= 0}] &
```

Compute a table of the first few terms of the series expansion `Rho[x]` about `x = 0`.

```
Table[{p, R^p Derivative[p][Rho][0]/p!} /. solnN /. {R -> 0.5}, {p, 0, 10}] // Grid

(* table showing nice series convergence, at least for this value of R *)
```

Here is a rough-and-ready routine (`0 < R < 0.82` or thereabouts) for numerically summing the series.

```
sumSeries[R_, error_ : 10^(-6)] :=
  Module[{term = 1, sum = 0, q = 0, qstep = 2, coefft},
   coefft = Derivative[p][Rho][0] /. solnN;
   While[Abs[term] > error,
    term = R^p coefft/p! /. p -> q;
    sum += term;
    q += qstep];
   sum
   ];
```

Plot `Rho[R]`.

```
Plot[sumSeries[R], {R, 0, 0.82}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 0.2}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"R", "Rho[R]"}]
```

[image]

This numerical result is very similar to the one computed by Alex Trounev. However I find that my series expansion diverges for `R > 0.82` or thereabouts.

Comment: This is nice approach (+1). We can simplifier this method using `NMinimize` - see Update  2 to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here I 'll show an iterative solution.

First the integralequation is  differentiated `D[....,R]` . This finally gives

`rho[R] == (v[R] v'[R])/(2 Pi R) + Integrate[rho[m] m^2  Sqrt[1 - e^2]/Sqrt[R^2 - e^2 m^2]^3 , {m, 0, R} ]`

This integralequation is solved `numerically` (using `NIntegrate` , `Interpolation` and `NestList`)

```
e = 0.995;
v[R_] := 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955] //Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Rmin = 0; Rmax = 10;
ni =  25;  
ri = Subdivide[0, Rmax, ni];

gfip[G_] := Block[{ R, m, zw = Simplify[(v[R] v'[R])/(2 Pi R)]},
Interpolation[Table[{R, 
 zw + NIntegrate[G[m] m^2  Sqrt[1 - e^2]/Sqrt[R^2 - e^2 m^2]^3 , {m, 0, R}  , 
   Method ->  "LocalAdaptive"  ] }, {R, ri}]   ]]
solf=solf = NestList[gfip, 0 &, 10]; 

Plot[ solf[[-1]] [R] , {R, 0, Rmax}, PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel -> {"R", "rho[R]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice approach (+1).  With small modification your solution consider with my solution for `R>0.2` at `Rmax=5`  - see Update 1 to my code.

Comment: @AlecTrounev Thanks! From the differentiated  integralequation I would expect `rho[0]==Limit[v[R]v'[R]/(2Pi R),R->0]==.025`, but your solution starts with `rho[0]==.18`. What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: You suppose that `Integrate[G[m] m^2  Sqrt[1 - e^2]/Sqrt[R^2 - e^2 m^2]^3 , {m, 0, R}]->0` at `R->0`. But it is not right. If we do the substitution `m->s R/e`, then we have `G[0] Sqrt[1 - e^2]/e^3 Integrate[s^2/Sqrt[1-s^2]^3,{s,0, e}]=G[0] int[e]`, where `int[0.995]=0.860958`. Therefore `rho[0]=.025/(1-int[e])=0.179802` :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, understood. "Wrong" integration variable is the reason for our different simulation results too?

Comment: I managed to improve your method, so now there is no discrepancy with the wavelet method. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

**modified: Case Rmax==25**

Inspired by the interesting discussion with Alex I found a direct approach, using a simple polygonal ansatz( borrowed from FEM). It solves the original integralequation, transformed via `m->s R/e`.

```
e = 0.995;
v[R_] := 0.342331 Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955] ;
Rmin = 0; Rmax = 25;
ni = 25 ; 

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

riGrid[n_] := 
Block[{dt, \[CapitalDelta]t0, \[CapitalDelta]t1, zw, sol}, 
dt = Map[ \[CapitalDelta]t0 + (\[CapitalDelta]t1 - \
\[CapitalDelta]t0) (#/Rmax)^2 &, Subdivide[0, Rmax, n]];
zw = Accumulate[dt] ;
sol = Solve[{zw[[1]] == 0,zw[[-1]] == Rmax}, {\[CapitalDelta]t0,\[CapitalDelta]t1}][[1]];
zw /. sol  // N]

ri=riGrid[ni]; (* problem adapted grid *)
\[Rho]i = Table[\[Rho][k], {k, 1, Length[ri]}];

netz = ToElementMesh[Map[{#} &, ri]]
\[Phi]i =Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[netz, #] &,IdentityMatrix[Length[ri]]];

Plot[Evaluate[Through[\[Phi]i[R]]], {R, 0, Rmax}]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

int[R_?NumericQ] := 
Block[{zwv = Function[{RR}, Evaluate[  v[RR] ^2/(4 Pi RR^2 ) ]]},
zwv[R] -Sqrt[1 - e^2]/e^3 NIntegrate[s^2 /Sqrt[1 - s^2] Through[\[Phi]i[s R/e]], {s, 0, e}, Method -> {"FiniteElement", "LocalAdaptive"}[[1]]] . \[Rho]i]

zwint = Table[int[R], {R, ri}] /. 0. -> 0 // Quiet;
mini0 = NMinimize[zwint . zwint, \[Rho]i ]
ListPlot[Rest@Transpose[{ri, \[Rho]i} /. mini0[[2]]],GridLines->{ri,None}]
```

[image]

The solution agrees quite well with solutions presented by Alex.

Comment: @ All Sorry , I was away the last few days. Thanks for your answers , this is very useful.

Comment: @All I need a solution from R=0 to R=10 , and I observe some oscillations in Alex proposal when R>5. Alex solution is fast but this is a decomposition in wavelets not very easy to manipulate...

Comment: @ Alex Thank you very muche for this great job. Why  is there oscillations if I change Rma to 10 ?  Because I need the solution between  {0,10} ?

Comment: @Alex and Ulrich Ulrich solution modified by Alex is fine. It looks like Picard solution of Volterra integral of second kind. This gives an Interpolating function easy to manipulate. But, where does come the factor 0.18 from ???

Comment: Thank you for your last solution using FEM. Naive question : how did you choose ri coefficients ?

Comment: @RémyGalli I took a grid which increases quadratically to get a finer mesh in the range `0,1` .

Comment: @RémyGalli From the fixpoint equation with `R->0`:  `rho[R]==v[R ] ^2/(4 Pi R^2 )  -Sqrt[1 - e^2]/e^3 NIntegrate[s^2 /Sqrt[1 - s^2] ,{s,0,e}] rho[R]  /.R->0` it follows `rho[0]=0.18`

Comment: OK very good Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on discretization of the integral using the trapezoid rule: yeah it's simple and naive, but it works!

As shown in other answers, the precision for small $R$ is a bit hard to raise. In this answer, the issue is resolved with graded mesh, which is part of the built-in FEM functionality.

In the following code I've also included a `solasymp` which is essentially a simplification of [Stephen Luttrell's method for small $R$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291793/1871).

```
e = 0.995;
vc[R_] = 0.342331  Sqrt[R^2/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955];

domain = {0, 5}; points = 1000;

<< NDSolve`FEM`
grid = ToGradedMesh[
     Line[List /@ domain], <|"Alignment" -> "Left", "ElementCount" -> points, 
      "GradingRatio" -> 1.01|>, MeshOrder -> 1]["Coordinates"] // Flatten;

Clear@int;
int[expr_, {var_, 0, r_?NumericQ}] := 
 With[{pos = Ordering[Abs[grid - r], 1][[1]]}, 
  trap[Function @@ {var, expr}, grid[[;; pos]]]]

trap[f_, grid_] := 
  With[{dlst = Differences@grid}, (Total[dlst (f /@ Most@grid + f /@ Rest@grid)])/2];

expr = (4 π Sqrt[1 - e^2] m^2 Rho[m])/Sqrt[-e^2 m^2 + R^2];
eq = vc[R]^2 == int[expr, {m, 0, R}];
ae = Table[eq, {R, Rest@grid}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.3569, Null} *)
    
solasymp[R_] = 
 Rho[R] /. First@
   Simplify[Solve[vc[R]^2 == AsymptoticIntegrate[expr, {m, 0, R}, R -> 0], Rho[R]], 
    R > 0]
(* 0.134143/(0.728117 + R^2)^0.87955 *)
    
sollst = LinearSolve[#2, -#1] & @@ 
    CoefficientArrays[ae, Rho /@ Rest@grid]; // AbsoluteTiming

Show[p, ListLinePlot[{grid // Rest, sollst}\[Transpose], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], Plot[solasymp[x], {x, 0, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> Gray]]
(* {5.58611, Null} *)
```

[image]

Definition of `p` is the same as that in [Alex's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291747/1871). We can see the numeric error for very small $R$ is a bit obvious, but given that the influenced domain is quite narrow, we can simply ignore it. Alternatively, we may turn to the asymptotic solution `solasymp` to supplement the function value for very small $R$.

Comment: Jump at `R->0` is not clear. We discussed with Ulrich that it should be `rho[0]=.025/(1-int[e])=0.179802`, where  `int[e]=Sqrt[1 - e^2]/e^3 Integrate[s^2/Sqrt[1-s^2]^3,{s,0, e}]`, and therefore `int[0.995]=0.860958`. But in your solution we see jump from 0.025 to 0.179802, same as in the wrong iterative solution in the first answer @Ulrich :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yeah but the jump area is quite narrow, we can simply treat it as numeric error (actually, I believe it's just numeric error, after checking various settings for `points`), and use the `solasymp` to supplement the function value for very small $R$ if necessary.

Comment: I see that you used asymptotic solution as well. We can exclude singularity at `R->0` by substitution `m=s R/e`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yeah, I've seen your clever treatment, but still decide to solve this problem in a manner as naive as possible :) .

Comment: @Alex I just took a closer look at the change of variable `m == R/e`. If I understand it correctly, this won't play a role in numeric solving (at least for my method, I haven't looked into other answers yet), because the `Rho` term always disappear for `R == 0`, so I'll only have equations for `Rho/@Rest@grid` in the end.

Comment: Do you mean `m=s R/e`? Also please pay attention that `Rho` term is not zero at R->0. You suppose that `Integrate[G[m] m^2  Sqrt[1 - e^2]/Sqrt[R^2 - e^2 m^2]^3 , {m, 0, R}]->0` at `R->0`. But it is not right.  :)

Comment: @Alex Oops, yeah it's a typo and should be `m==s R/e`. I mean, in the implementation of trapezoid rule, the `Rho[0]` term always disappear when `m == 0`, so the singularity at `R==0` doesn't influence my method. (As shown above, The `Rho[0]` term is not solved in my answer. ) And my method doesn't differentiate the equation, so I think the `Integrate[G[m] m^2  Sqrt[1 - e^2]/Sqrt[R^2 - e^2 m^2]^3 , {m, 0, R}]` is not related here. My explanation for the numeric error is, the grid is too coarse for small $R$, this also explains why a graded grid improves the accuracy.