# Galactic rotation speed and density research

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

Rotation speed of Milky Way looks like this until about 25 kpc

[image]

I know the following points to describe this curve

```
{{0.1, 0.566016}, {0.11, 0.575781}, {0.121, 0.5875}, {0.133, 
  0.600781}, {0.146, 0.620703}, {0.161, 0.653906}, {0.177, 
  0.703516}, {0.195, 0.767969}, {0.214, 0.834375}, {0.236, 
  0.889844}, {0.259, 0.929297}, {0.285, 0.954688}, {0.314, 
  0.969531}, {0.345, 0.977344}, {0.38, 0.980469}, {0.418, 
  0.979297}, {0.459, 0.975391}, {0.505, 0.96875}, {0.556, 
  0.960547}, {0.612, 0.95}, {0.673, 0.936719}, {0.74, 
  0.921094}, {0.814, 0.905078}, {0.895, 0.889844}, {0.985, 
  0.876953}, {1.083, 0.866016}, {1.192, 0.855859}, {1.311, 
  0.846875}, {1.442, 0.838672}, {1.586, 0.830859}, {1.745, 
  0.823828}, {1.919, 0.818359}, {2.111, 0.814453}, {2.323, 
  0.813281}, {2.555, 0.816016}, {2.81, 0.823047}, {3.091, 
  0.833594}, {3.4, 0.848438}, {3.74, 0.867188}, {4.114, 
  0.885156}, {4.526, 0.896484}, {4.979, 0.904688}, {5.476, 
  0.914453}, {6.024, 0.926563}, {6.626, 0.935547}, {7.289, 
  0.937891}, {8.018, 0.933594}, {8.82, 0.924609}, {9.702, 
  0.916016}, {10.672, 0.914844}, {11.739, 0.926172}, {12.913, 
  0.948438}, {14.204, 0.970703}, {15.625, 0.975391}, {17.187, 
  0.961719}, {18.906, 0.950391}, {20.797, 0.952734}, {22.876, 
  0.959375}, {25.164, 0.951953}}
```

We could Interpolate and get an Interpolating fonction vc[R] to solve the following problem :

Knowing e=0.995, I am trying now to get the density Rho[m]from the equation

vc[R]^2 == Integrate[(4 Pi Sqrt[1 - e^2] m^2  Rho[m])/  Sqrt[-e^2 m^2 + R^2], {m, 0, R}]
This equation comes from Galactic Dynamics Binney Tremaine 2008. (2.132)

But solutions given elswhere [Galactic rotation curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291982/1871) are working only with an analytical function vc[R], and I dont know why ??

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your new dataset doesn't contain point `R=0`!

Comment: Have a look at the transformed integral equation. The expression `v[R]^2/(4Pi R^2)` must be finite for all values of R.

Comment: @ Ulrich Yes,you are right and I noticed these two points but I cant find something working. with this Interpolating function. ....

Comment: 1. Please add the link to that "solutions given elswhere" to the body of your question. 2. [My solution under your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291982/1871) fully applys to this new `vc`, which part are you having difficulty? (Of course you need to supplement the missing data at `R==0`. )

Comment: @RémyGalli In a case of our Galaxy the density has a singular part $m\delta(R)$, where $m$ is the black hole mass (see Nobel prize 2020). Therefore equation for `vc[R]` should be update.

Comment: Please show us your failed trial so we can diagnose. As mentioned in my last comment, my solution just works fine on the new `vc` according to my test.

Comment: @xzczd  Sorry, I have no mean to recover this trial : I scratched it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dataset should include point `R=0`. That's why I added point `{0,0}`.

With the transformed integralequation `v[R]^2=Integrate[...,{s,0,e}]`
the solution evaluates.

```
e = 0.995;
 
    v = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.566016}, {0.11, 0.575781}, {0.121, 
     0.5875}, {0.133, 0.600781}, {0.146, 0.620703}, {0.161, 
     0.653906}, {0.177, 0.703516}, {0.195, 0.767969}, {0.214, 
     0.834375}, {0.236, 0.889844}, {0.259, 0.929297}, {0.285, 
     0.954688}, {0.314, 0.969531}, {0.345, 0.977344}, {0.38, 
     0.980469}, {0.418, 0.979297}, {0.459, 0.975391}, {0.505, 
     0.96875}, {0.556, 0.960547}, {0.612, 0.95}, {0.673, 
     0.936719}, {0.74, 0.921094}, {0.814, 0.905078}, {0.895, 
     0.889844}, {0.985, 0.876953}, {1.083, 0.866016}, {1.192, 
     0.855859}, {1.311, 0.846875}, {1.442, 0.838672}, {1.586, 
     0.830859}, {1.745, 0.823828}, {1.919, 0.818359}, {2.111, 
     0.814453}, {2.323, 0.813281}, {2.555, 0.816016}, {2.81, 
     0.823047}, {3.091, 0.833594}, {3.4, 0.848438}, {3.74, 
     0.867188}, {4.114, 0.885156}, {4.526, 0.896484}, {4.979, 
     0.904688}, {5.476, 0.914453}, {6.024, 0.926563}, {6.626, 
     0.935547}, {7.289, 0.937891}, {8.018, 0.933594}, {8.82, 
     0.924609}, {9.702, 0.916016}, {10.672, 0.914844}, {11.739, 
     0.926172}, {12.913, 0.948438}, {14.204, 0.970703}, {15.625, 
     0.975391}, {17.187, 0.961719}, {18.906, 0.950391}, {20.797, 
     0.952734}, {22.876, 0.959375}, {25.164, 0.951953}}
   ];

Rmin = 0; Rmax = 25;
ni = 25;
```

FEM approach:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

riGrid[n_] := 
Block[{dt, \[CapitalDelta]t0, \[CapitalDelta]t1, zw, sol}, 
dt = Map[\[CapitalDelta]t0 + (\[CapitalDelta]t1 - \[CapitalDelta]t0)(#/Rmax)^2 &, Subdivide[0, Rmax, n]];
zw = Accumulate[dt];
sol = Solve[{zw[[1]] == Rmin,zw[[-1]] == Rmax}, 
{\[CapitalDelta]t0,\[CapitalDelta]t1}][[1]];
zw /. sol // N
]



ri = riGrid[ni];(*problem adapted grid*)
(*{0., 0.00452489, 0.0226244, 0.0633484, 0.135747, 0.248869,0.411765,0.633484, 0.923077, 1.28959, 1.74208, 2.28959,2.94118, 3.70588, 4.59276, 5.61086, 6.76923, 8.07692, 9.54299, 11.1765,12.9864,14.9819, 17.1719, 19.5656, 22.1719, 25.}*)



\[Rho]i =Table[\[Rho][k], {k, 1, Length[ri]}];

netz = ToElementMesh[Map[{#} &, ri]];
\[Phi]i =Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[netz, #]&,IdentityMatrix[Length[ri]]];

Plot[Evaluate[Through[\[Phi]i[R]]], {R, Rmin, Rmax}];
int[R_?NumericQ] :=Block[{ },v[R]^2 - 4 Pi R^2 Sqrt[1 - e^2]/e^3
NIntegrate[
s^2/Sqrt[1 - s^2] Through[\[Phi]i[s R/e]], {s, 0, e}, 
Method -> {"FiniteElement", "LocalAdaptive"}[[1]]] . \[Rho]i]

zwint = Table[int[R], {R, ri}] /. 0. -> 0 // Quiet;

mini0 = NMinimize[zwint . zwint, \[Rho]i]
(*{-1.73472*10^-18, {\[Rho][1] -> 0.0352952, \[Rho][2] -> 0.206768, \[Rho][3] -> 0.170064, \[Rho][4] -> 0.178969, \[Rho][5] -> 0.171873,
\[Rho][6] -> 
0.161654, \[Rho][7] -> 0.138237, \[Rho][8] -> 0.10491, \[Rho][9] ->
0.0706109, \[Rho][10] -> 0.0444486, \[Rho][11] -> 
0.0275268, \[Rho][12] -> 0.0172977, \[Rho][13] -> 
0.0111636, \[Rho][14] -> 0.0074253, \[Rho][15] -> 
0.00507642, \[Rho][16] -> 0.00356313, \[Rho][17] -> 
0.00255434, \[Rho][18] -> 0.00187092, \[Rho][19] -> 
0.00139474, \[Rho][20] -> 0.0010538, \[Rho][21] -> 
0.000810122, \[Rho][22] -> 0.000628789, \[Rho][23] -> 
0.000496635, \[Rho][24] -> 0.000392479, \[Rho][25] -> 
0.000317462, \[Rho][26] -> 0.000254499}}*)


ListPlot[ Transpose[{ri, \[Rho]i} /. mini0[[2]]],GridLines -> {ri,None}]
```

[image]

**Interpolation&Gaussian quadrature** :

```
swGauss =GaussianQuadratureWeights[  15, 0, e] ; 



JJ = Sum[{1, 1/(1 + (R/2)^4)  }[[-1]] 
(v[R]^2  -4 Pi R^2   Sqrt[1 - e^2]/e^3 
Total@Map[#[[2]] #[[1]]^2 /Sqrt[1 - #[[1]]^2]Interpolation[Transpose[{Rationalize[ri], \[Rho]i}]][#[[1]]R/e] & ,swGauss] )^2, {R, ri}];

mini00 = NMinimize[{JJ  ,Map[# > 0 &, \[Rho]i] }, \[Rho]i] 
ListPlot[Rest@Transpose[{ri, \[Rho]i} /. mini00[[2]]],GridLines -> {ri, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: I get negative values : could give the {ri,rhoi} please ? Thanks

Comment: Orbital velocity is about  7,650 km/s in central part of Galaxy since there is the black hole  Sagittarius A*.  :)

Comment: @RémyGalli Rerun my code with fresh kernel. `ri` and `mini0` show you the values of these parameters.

Comment: @Ulrich sorry Ulrich Could you display the ri and \[Rho]i because i get a lot of negative values Thanks in advance....

Comment: @RémyGalli I modified my answer with displayed `ri, rhoi` ! Still I don't understand, why my code (with fresh kernel) doesn't evaluate in your Mathematica session.

Comment: @ Ulrich This is strange, now that works after rebooting all....So, thank you very much, Ulrich !

Comment: @r Sounds like certain variables are polluted. When using _Mathematica_ you should always pay attention to the color of variable. "Empty" variable is _usually_ blue, otherwise it's black. If you see undesired black variable, `Clear` it. (And please remember, simply open a new notebook won't clear the variable! )